# Why do I need "\$$(variable)" instead of "$$(variable)" to get "$(variable)"?

Tags: makefile

```
new_contents = "\$$(cooly)"

all:
    mkdir -p subdir
    echo $(new_contents) | sed -e 's/^ //' > subdir/makefile
    @echo "---MAKEFILE CONTENTS---"
    @cd subdir && cat makefile
    @echo "---END MAKEFILE CONTENTS---"
    #cd subdir && $(MAKE)

# Note that variables and exports. They are set/affected globally.
cooly = "The subdirectory can see me!"
export cooly
# This would nullify the line above: unexport cooly

clean:
    rm -rf subdir
```

What I want is a `"$(cooly)"` string, not the variable value.

I tried several combinations:

1. `new_contents = "$(cooly)"`, gives the variable value, `The subdirectory can see me!`
2. `new_contents = "$$"`, gives `$`
3. `new_contents = "\$(cooly)"`, gives `Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` error

Why `new_contents = "$$(cooly)"` doesn't give `"$(cooly)"` but result in nothing?

`"$$"` -> `"$"`, so why isn't `"$$(cooly)"` ---> `"$(cooly)"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand *both* how make expansion works, *and* how shell expansion works, in order to write more complicated recipes in make.  That's because, make recipes are passed to the shell after make is done expanding them.

Make passes recipe lines to the shell virtually verbatim: there is only one character that's special (not counting backslash/newlines at the end) and that's `$`.  If make sees a `$` it will try to expand it as a variable reference.  To avoid that, you have to escape it as `$$` to hide it from make.

So let's look at your makefile:

```
cooly = "The subdirectory can see me!"

echo $(new_contents) ...
```

If `new_contents` is `"$(cooly)"`, make sees the `$(cooly)` as a variable reference and expands it before it even invokes the shell.  So first make expands `$(new_contents)` to `"$(cooly)"`, then it expands that to `""The subdirectory can see me!""` (because the quotes are in both variables, and quotes are not special to make: they're just like any other character like `a` or `b`).  The result will be:

```
echo ""The subdirectory can see me!""
```

The shell will toss the quotes since they're no-ops and echo that value (into the pipe).

If `new_contents` is `"\$(cooly)"`, that backslash doesn't mean anything to make.  Just like quotes, backslashes (unless they are at the end of a line) are not special to make.  So make expands just as before, but this time the command it passes to the shell is this:

```
echo "\"The subdirectory can see me!""
```

backslashes are not special to make, but they *are* special to the shell.  Here you've escaped the second quote so the shell doesn't treat it as a quote character, which means you have an odd number of quotes in your command, which is why you get an error from the shell about non-terminated quotes.

If `new_contents` is `"$$(cooly)"`, make doesn't expand the variable, it is passed along to the shell like this:

```
echo "$(cooly)"
```

However, `$` is *also* special to the shell.  Putting it in double quotes doesn't prevent the shell from trying to expand it.  This tells the shell to run the command `cooly` and substitute the output.  Almost certainly there is no command named `cooly` and so you'll get an error message to stderr (maybe you didn't notice it) and the shell will replace it with nothing because it didn't print anything to stdout.

If `new_contents` is `"\$$(cooly)"` then make will not expand, and run this shell command:

```
echo "\$(cooly)"
```

The shell sees the backslash and doesn't expand the `$` but instead uses it literally, and you get the result you want.

Here are some hints:

First, do not include quotes in your make variables (unless the variable contains an entire shell command and you need quotes inside it).  Make doesn't care about quotes and having them embedded in variables makes it very difficult to reason about what the shell will see.

Include the quotes only in the recipe.

Second, remember that since make doesn't care about quotes, it doesn't have the same behavior as the shell WRT single vs. double quotes.  You can use single quotes around make variables to reduce the need to escape things from the shell, without hiding them from make.

So, I would write this:

```
new_contents = $$(cooly)

cooly = The subdirectory can see me!

all:
        mkdir -p subdir
        echo '$(new_contents)' | sed -e 's/^ //' > subdir/makefile
          ...
```

BTW, it's never a good idea to add `@` values to your makefile until it's completely done and working.  Seeing the output make prints (which is what it's sending to the shell) is a great help in figuring out whether your recipes are right, and whether the problem is with your make constructs or shell constructs.

Comment: Holy crap!! You clarified everything. I read through every single word of your answer. Thank you 1000 times ;)